# Entity Framework + SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

Базы не существует, делаю через Code First. Нужно, чтобы бд и все таблицы создавались автоматически по классам моделей.

Подключаю System.Data.SQLite.EF6 через NuGet, прописываю конфиги подключения, создаю модели, контекст, дальше ошибки.

Конфиги (были созданы автоматически, прописал только connectionStrings):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbConnection" connectionString="Data Source=C:\test.db;Version=3" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Контекст:

```
public class ProjectContext : DbContext
{
    public ProjectContext() : base("DbConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

В результате выкидывает исключение на строчке public ProjectContext() : base("DbConnection")

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" в
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: The Entity Framework provider type
>   'System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices,
>   System.Data.SQLite.EF6' registered in the application config file for
>   the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6'
>   could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is
>   used and that the assembly is available to the running application.
>   See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more
>   information.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где накосячил?

UPD:
Добавил System.Data.SQLite с NuGet'a, контекст создается нормально. Однако теперь выдает исключение при попытке добавить объект модели в DbSet контекста:

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with
>   invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite'.

Comment: EF6 не умеет создавать базу SQLite, придётся создавать руками.

Comment: @ixSci , читал об этом, думал поправили. Скажите, а таблицы создавать/изменять может? С миграциями работает?

Comment: Я не углублялся, но, насколько я понимаю, что именно из-за неумения работать с миграциями, этот плагин и не пытается создавать базу. Но EF Core уже поддерживает SQLite, поэтому, если есть возможность, посмотрите в эту сторону.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно же еще с нугет подтянуть библиотечки для работы `EF` c `SQLite`, конкретно `System.Data.SQLite`.

Лично я так делал, немного не по хипстерски, зато работает.

```
private static SQLiteConnection CreateConnection(string path)
{
    var builder = (SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder)SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance.CreateConnectionStringBuilder();
    if (builder == null) return null;

    builder.DataSource = path;
    builder.FailIfMissing = false;
    return new SQLiteConnection(builder.ToString());
}

/// <summary>
/// Контекст для создания БД
/// </summary>
private sealed class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext() : base(CreateConnection(DataBaseConnectionString), false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TaskBase> Tasks { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        if (!File.Exists(DataBaseConnectionString))
        {
            var initializer = new SQLite.CodeFirst.SqliteDropCreateDatabaseAlways<AppDbContext>(modelBuilder);
            Database.SetInitializer(initializer);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

    }
```

В `App.config` (или `Web.config` в случае `ASP`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" /><add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" /></DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data></configuration>
```

Comment: Раньше работал с MS SQL, там передавал `DbConnection`, работало нормально, осталось оттуда. К SQLite пытаюсь подключиться впервые, тонкостей пока не знаю, очевидно делаю не правильно. При подключении к SQLite имя подключения передавать не нужно? Дополнил вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста. Теперь ругается на подключение, видимо как раз из-за имени.

Comment: Ок, скопировал из своего проекта.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Также пришлось подтянуть SQLite.CodeFirst с нугета.